# Existence of a non - square solution to a modular equation (Y)

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, legendre-symbol

Let $p_1, \dots, p_l \in \mathbb{Z}$ be pairwise disjoint odd primes.

By the Chinese remainder follows there exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying

\begin{align*}
x & = 1 \text{ mod } 4 \cdot p_2 \cdot \dots \cdot p_l\\
x & = a \text{ mod } p_1
\end{align*}
for some $0 \leq a < p_1$.

But is there always a solution if we want $a$ not to be a square in $F_{p_1}^*$?

For this we can rewrite the system of equations using the Legendre symbol:

\begin{align*}
x & = 1 \text{ mod } 4 \cdot p_2 \cdot \dots \cdot p_l\\
\left( \frac{x}{p_1} \right)& = -1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Why would we care about whether $\;a\;$ is a square or not? The CRT doesn't condition that...

Comment: My statement about the CRT is just what i know. I don't know if we can use the CRT to answer the question. The question comes from following problem: Given a character $\chi$ modulo $m = 4 p_1\cdot \dots \cdot p_l$ with the property that $\chi(p)$ = $\left(\frac{p_1 \cdot \dots \cdot p_l}{p} \right)$ for all primes $p$ not dividing $m$ is non-trivial.

Comment: I don't really know what the original problem is and I won't get into that right now. Again. CRT makes sure there's always a solution under the first line condtion, no matter what $\;a\;$ is.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. So the question reduces to: $\exists x \in F_p^*$ for any prime $p$ such that $x$ is not a square in $F_p^*$? And this is true, because there are always exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ squares in $F_p^*$. Therefore there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ non-squares in $F_p^*$. Is this right?

Comment: Well, now you seem to be asking way another question: whether $\;x\;$, "the" solution to a CRT problem, is or isn't a square modulo whatever. I suppose this time the answer could be different, but I really don't know: we should probably check case by case.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the question I had in mind at the beginning. I'm sorry, that I couldn't write it down properly. Which different cases should we check?

Comment: @Well, modulo a prime it can be a unique solution and you can't do much to change it, I think. For example, if you want $\;x=1\pmod {24}\;,\;\;x=4\pmod 7\;$ , then $\;x=25\;$ is a solution, but $\;25=4\pmod 7\;$ is **the unique** solution modulo $\;7\;$ and you can't change it...